# How to fix the parse error when loading phpmyadmin?

Tags: php

when loading localhost/PHPMyAdmin getting a parse error on this line of code in the PHPMyAdmin code downloaded from the internet

```
echo $controller->index([
        'formset' => $_GET['formset'] ?? null,
    ]);
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The null coalescing operator `??` was only introduced in PHP 7, so that could be it.

Comment: Of course, if you're not using PHP 7, who knows what else you're doing wrong? PHP 7 came out about 5 years ago. Are you really 5+ years out of date?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to upgrade to PHP 7, or to change the code to

```
echo $controller->index([
        'formset' => (isset($_GET['formset']) ? $_GET['formset']) : null,
    ]);
```